# How to allocate memory to a char pointer in a struct in C?

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc, allocation

I'm using this structure below, but it's limited if I want to get all String from a huge file...

```
typedef struct arr {
    char name[200]; // Could be a number higher than 200 here...
} array;
```

Now, if I use...

```
typedef struct arr {
    char *name;
} array;
```

Then, is it possible to allocate memory for a char pointer (*name) that is inside a struct (array)?

I don't know what I did wrong, I allocate memory for array, but somehow, I got a Segmentation fault error. The struct with `name[200]` didn't give me any error. The struct with `*name` does.

```
array *str = malloc(sizeof(*str));
```

Did I miss to allocate something else?

Comment: By the way, [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Is it correct if I write `array *str = malloc(sizeof(*str));` instead?

Comment: Allocate the struct itself first `array *str = malloc(sizeof(array));` and then your string `str->name = malloc(200);`

Answer (score 3):

> Did I miss to allocate something else?

Yes. You allocated memory for an `array` but not for `name` inside the `array`.

You need:

```
array *str = malloc(sizeof(array));
if ( str == NULL )
{
   // Deal with the error
}

str->name = malloc(200);
```

Comment: Just curious, why arr->name and not array->name?

Comment: @LordRixuel, that was a typo, It needs to be `str->name`.

Comment: Or even: `array str; str.name = malloc(200);` without dynamically allocating the variable but just the space it points at.  It would also probably be sensible to record how much space is allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Your first allocation method allocates a region of memory with 200 chars as you explicitly code the amount of memory you want. Your second allocation method will only allocate space for the constituent pointer. So allocate the struct first, then allocate space for the constituent pointer explicitly.

```
array *str = (array*)malloc(sizeof(array));
int n = 200;
str->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
```

Comment: You don't need to cast malloc() result

Answer (score 0):

yes you can allocate memory to a char pointer inside an structure

```
array *str = (array *)malloc(sizeof(array));
if ( str == NULL )
{
   printf("Memory allocation failed \n")
   exit (0);
}
str->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*200);
if (str->name)
{
   printf("Memory allocation failed \n")
   exit (0);
}
...
//use free() to destroy the memory allocated after use.
free(str->name);   //first destroy the memory for the variable inside the structure
free(str);  //destroy the memory allocated to the object.
```

than after the use of the pointer '*str' and '*name' use 'free()' to destroy the memory allocated dynamically. First free the '*name' than '*str'.